# Direct image and infinite suspension

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, motivic-homotopy, stable-homotopy-category

I have a basic doubt regarding infinite suspension functor and the direct image. I write it for schemes but I guess it works the same for the topological setting so I welcome answers also from the topological setting. Let $f\colon Y\to X$ be a morphism of schemes, then we have direct image functors
$$
f_*\colon \mathbf{H}_\bullet(Y)\longrightarrow \mathbf{H}_\bullet (X) \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ f_*\colon \mathbf{SH}(Y) \longrightarrow \mathbf{SH}(X).
$$
Let $\Sigma^\infty\colon \mathbf{H}_\bullet(Y)\longrightarrow \mathbf{SH}(Y) $ be the infinite suspension functor.

> **Question:** Are there conditions so that $\Sigma^\infty f_*$ equals $f_*\Sigma^\infty$? That is to say, are there conditions so that diagram 
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   $$ 
> \begin{CD}
> \mathbf{H}_\bullet(Y)@>\Sigma^\infty >>\mathbf{SH}(Y)\\
> @Vf_* VV@VVf_*V\\
> \mathbf{H}_\bullet(X)@>\Sigma^\infty>>
> \mathbf{SH}(X)
> \end{CD}
> $$
>   commutes?

I think that no. By abstract nonsense there is a natural transformation $\Sigma^\infty f_* \longrightarrow f_*\Sigma^\infty$ (cf. map 1.2.5.1 [from here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.2110.pdf)) but I fail to produce an example that allows me to have some intuition on this, even assuming $f$ to be smooth. On the classic theory of sheaves in classic topology we have the formula that sais $R^nf_*\mathcal{F}_x=H_c^n(f^{-1}(x),\mathcal{F})$, but I fail to see the role that infinite suspension would play in a formula like that.